# Are there a wiki in sharepoint that supports markdown?

Tags: wiki

I'm wondering if there are a wiki for SharePoint that supports markdown? Or if there are a way to change the existing one so that it can be edited using markdown.

Answer (score 6):

The community kit for SP - Enhanced Wiki Edition on [CodePlex](http://cks.codeplex.com/workitem/1623?ProjectName=cks) has a wiki which provides custom wiki markup and tokens.